# generating multi classifier training data from document

Tags: python, nlp, classification

I am looking for guidance to generate multiple classifier training data from document. e.g. if particular document has three sections with each 10 pages in each sections. (total 30 pages)

I am looking for open source library, where I can pass on document (explicitly specifying section 1, section 2 and section 3 pages) then it can give me list of important words to be used as training data to identify "section 1" vs "section 2" vs "section 3". (multiple classification)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to generate training data for a classifier in this way: logically, if one can create the gold-standard labels using this open-source library, then there's no point training an classifier (statistical, so it makes errors) since the library can automatically produce the correct labels, In reality, the library (if it exists) would  also be imperfect, which means that the classifier would be trained on noisy data. And finally there is the problem of defining formally what is an 'important word'. Basically your task is not well defined, it needs to be better specified.

Comment: Also this is not a programming but a design question, it should be asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Important word is just removing stop words and then comparing rest of words by sections. Library will be open source but document will be specific to solve particular problem.

Comment: If you just want to remove stop words then it's very easy: you can do this with any NLP library, for instance [NLTK](https://pythonspot.com/nltk-stop-words/) or [Spacy](https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/tutorial-for-stopwords-in-spacy/). But after you do this, you will discover that what is left is probably not what you consider 'important words', and definitely not usable as classification targets. You probably have an idea in your head of which words are 'important', but the computer is not going to guess it. You should formalize the problem first, otherwise results will be disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this quite a long time ago and I am not sure if it will help you at all but a book called "Deep Learning with Python" by François Chollet 2018 could give you some clues in terms of how to generate such data samples from your document. However, the drawback might be that you would have to prepare such a document in a certain way before you can generate data samples. My comment is based on the fact that I have read something about it a long time ago so I could misremember it. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. I am trying to automate process to generate training data as it requires lot of effort. Initial batch of document are well organized by classifier (by page range). I thought my scenario is not unique and thought some easy to use library out there.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a relevant answer, it's a book recommendation for a book about DL. Basically every question about ML could be answered with this kind of vague suggestion, but it's not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I get what you mean but I have decided to let the guy above know because one of my friends had a similar task to do and he said that this book and some other online data was the way he handled it. I could give him this clue or leave this question unanswered. Personally, I also think that step by step answer to the question would be much better but its always better than nothing.